# I cannot loop through a dataframe because the column is read as string

Tags: python, pandas, string, loops

this is my exampe dataframe and the loop I am trying to pass through it. I also attach the error I get.

Example dataframe:

```
 x   Replicate  y
 1      1       0.39   
 2      2       0.08
 3      3       1.46
```

My code:

```
df = file[['x', 'Replicate', 'y']].copy()
df.columns = ['x', 'Replicate', 'y']
grouped = df.groupby(['Obs', 'Replicate']).mean()

######################## functions ##########################
def model(t, a, b, c):
 return (a-b)* np.exp(-c*t) + b

####################### curve fitting #######################
for g in grouped:
 print(type(g))
 # Specify initial guess
 a = g['y'].max()
 b = g['y'].min()
 c = 0.36
```

error message:
a = g['y'].max()
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: What is `print (df.y.dtype)` ?

Comment: @jezrael it is float64

Comment: What is `'Obs'`, another column in your dataframe?

Comment: from the construction of grouped, I think when you do `for g in grouped`, then `g` will be the name of the columns of `grouped`, if your point is to apply the function `model` per group of Obs and Replicate, then try to define grouped as `grouped = df.groupby(['Obs', 'Replicate'])` without the `mean` and then to `for _, g in grouped:`

Comment: @Ben.T, thank you. I removed mean and now it seems to work.